# How to judge a Java program's runtime memory usage dynamically?

Tags: java, jvm, jmx

when we define a Java class, we can get the Obeject's memory usage in heap,but we cannot get the runtime memory usage becasuse of the program's unknown behaviors。such as the follow class:

```
public class Sample{
   private int age;
   private String name;
   private static List scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     while(sc.hasNext()){
       scores.add(sc.nextInt());
     }
   }
}
```

then how do we get the runtime memory usage of the class Sample?

Comment: There are a number of techniques outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535189/jvm-deep-memory-size-of-an-object

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple tools to do so. you can use jvisualvm which is in your JDK. Alternatively, there are some commercial ones too. for further information, you can follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). Moreover, you can install "visual GC" plugin on jvisualvm which shows you change on different parts of your heap e.g.: Eden, survivors, old gen, metaspace. Even time to perform GC and time to load classes are trackable.

To install a plugin on jvisualvm from Tools->plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can get another java parameters such as "Used Memory" like this:

```
public class Sample{
   private int age;
   private String name;
   private static List scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     while(sc.hasNext()){
       scores.add(sc.nextInt());
     }

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        System.out.println("Used Memory:" 
            + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()));

        System.out.println("Free Memory:" 
            + runtime.freeMemory());

        System.out.println("Total Memory:" + runtime.totalMemory());

        System.out.println("Max Memory:" + runtime.maxMemory());
   }
}
```

if you like to calculate a class usage you have to get this params before and after run than class and compare the numbers